# Issue with Android Maven Plugin

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I'm very new with management dependencies with maven on android. Actually I achieved configure in the new Android Studio the management configuration dependencies with Gradle, but I not achieve configure the pom.xml to make deploy with this plugin.

My pom.xml looks like

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- Repositories Configuration -->
<repositories>
    <!-- Spring Maven Release Repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Maven Central Repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>Central Repository</id>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<!-- Project Properties -->
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>    
    <android.sdk.platform>19</android.sdk.platform>
</properties>

<!-- Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
<!-- Android -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Json -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- Build -->
<build>
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
<sourceDirectory>app/src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Facilitates downloading source and javadoc in Eclipse -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     <!-- Android -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
      <androidManifestFile>app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
      <resourceDirectory>app/src/main/res</resourceDirectory>
      <assetsDirectory>app/src/main/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <sdk>
        <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                    <platform>${android.sdk.platform}</platform>
                </sdk>
      <dex>
        <jvmArguments>
          <jvmArgument>-Xms256m</jvmArgument>
          <jvmArgument>-Xmx512m</jvmArgument>
        </jvmArguments>
      </dex>          
      <emulator>
        <avd>Nexus4</avd>
      </emulator>
      <attachJar>auto</attachJar>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

But each time that I run the command **mvn clean package** I get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:andr
    oid-maven-plugin:3.8.2:dex (default-dex) on project stock-control: MojoExecution
    Exception: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\
    jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin\java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar X:\development\android-studio\sd
    k\build-tools\android-4.4W\lib\dx.jar --dex --output=X:\google-drive\work\projec
    ts\leibran\android\stock-control\application\src\stock-control\target\classes.de
    x C:\home\m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar C:
    \home\m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.4.2\jackson-da
    tabind-2.4.2.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar
    C:\home\m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.1\httpclient-4.0.
    1.jar C:\home\m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.4.2\jackso
    n-core-2.4.2.jar C:\home\m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\com
    mons-logging-1.1.1.jar C:\home\m2\repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.2\xmlParse
    rAPIs-2.6.2.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\h
    ttpcore-4.0.1.jar C:\home\m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3\1.1.4c\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar C:\home
    \m2\repository\org\khronos\opengl-api\gl1.1-android-2.1_r1\opengl-api-gl1.1-andr
    oid-2.1_r1.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\springframework\android\spring-android-
    rest-template\1.0.1.RELEASE\spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar C:\ho
    me\m2\repository\org\springframework\android\spring-android-core\1.0.1.RELEASE\s
    pring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar C:\home\m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson
    \core\jackson-annotations\2.4.0\jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar X:\google-drive\wo
    rk\projects\leibran\android\stock-control\application\src\stock-control\target\c
    lasses C:\home\m2\repository\com\google\android\android\4.1.1.4\android-4.1.1.4.
    jar", Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal c
    om.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:dex (defa
    ult-dex) on project stock-control:
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
    .java:216)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
    .java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
    .java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
    ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
    ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
    adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
    eStarter.java:120)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
    cher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
    a:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
    uncher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
    356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
            at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase08preparepackage.DexMojo.runDex
    (DexMojo.java:411)
            at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase08preparepackage.DexMojo.execut
    e(DexMojo.java:159)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
    BuildPluginManager.java:132)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
    .java:208)
            ... 19 more
    Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001:
     Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin\java -X
    ms256m -Xmx512m -jar X:\development\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\
    lib\dx.jar --dex --output=X:\google-drive\work\projects\leibran\android\stock-co
    ntrol\application\src\stock-control\target\classes.dex C:\home\m2\repository\com
    mons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar C:\home\m2\repository\com\fas
    terxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.4.2\jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar C:\home\m2
    \repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\a
    pache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.1\httpclient-4.0.1.jar C:\home\m2\repository
    \com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.4.2\jackson-core-2.4.2.jar C:\home\m2
    \repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar C:\h
    ome\m2\repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.2\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar C:\home\m2\
    repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.jar C:\home\m
    2\repository\xpp3\xpp3\1.1.4c\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\khronos\
    opengl-api\gl1.1-android-2.1_r1\opengl-api-gl1.1-android-2.1_r1.jar C:\home\m2\r
    epository\org\springframework\android\spring-android-rest-template\1.0.1.RELEASE
    \spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\spring
    framework\android\spring-android-core\1.0.1.RELEASE\spring-android-core-1.0.1.RE
    LEASE.jar C:\home\m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2
    .4.0\jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar X:\google-drive\work\projects\leibran\android
    \stock-control\application\src\stock-control\target\classes C:\home\m2\repositor
    y\com\google\android\android\4.1.1.4\android-4.1.1.4.jar", Result = 1
            at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$DefaultComma
    ndExecutor.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:246)
            at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase08preparepackage.DexMojo.runDex
    (DexMojo.java:407)
            ... 22 more
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
    d the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
    xception
```

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

**EDIT**

@MirMasej, I followed your steps specified in your comment and I got this.

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin> cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin\java -Xm
s256m -Xmx512m -jar X:\development\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\l
ib\dx.jar --dex --output=X:\google-drive\work\projects\leibran\android\stock-con
trol\application\src\stock-control\target\classes.dex C:\home\m2\repository\comm
ons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar C:\home\m2\repository\com\fast
erxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.4.2\jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar C:\home\m2\
repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\ap
ache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.1\httpclient-4.0.1.jar C:\home\m2\repository\
com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.4.2\jackson-core-2.4.2.jar C:\home\m2\
repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar C:\ho
me\m2\repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.2\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar C:\home\m2\r
epository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.jar C:\home\m2
\repository\xpp3\xpp3\1.1.4c\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\khronos\o
pengl-api\gl1.1-android-2.1_r1\opengl-api-gl1.1-android-2.1_r1.jar C:\home\m2\re
pository\org\springframework\android\spring-android-rest-template\1.0.1.RELEASE\
spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar C:\home\m2\repository\org\springf
ramework\android\spring-android-core\1.0.1.RELEASE\spring-android-core-1.0.1.REL
EASE.jar C:\home\m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.
4.0\jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar X:\google-drive\work\projects\leibran\android\
stock-control\application\src\stock-control\target\classes C:\home\m2\repository
\com\google\android\android\4.1.1.4\android-4.1.1.4.jar
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

1 error; aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have java in

> "c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\bin\java".

If yes, try running the whole command printed by maven:

> cmd.exe /X /C "c:\Java\ blah blah blah android\4.1.1.4\android-4.1.1.4.jar"

from command line and check the message.

Comment: I got an error, I updated my question to know if you know how to solve. Thanks.

Comment: @edla.sk8 see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12409475/2747533). android.4.1.1.4.jar should not be on your classpath.

Comment: I checked my .m2 home and the jar is there

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's there. Try adding provided scope for your android dependency: <scope>provided</scope>